# In the task manager why does Cefsharp created browser instance does not show embedded browser webview where as webview2 shows?

Tags: webbrowser-control, chromium, cefsharp, webview2

I created a browser instance using Cefsharp library. In the task manager I see only the below processes and not `embedded browser webview`.

[image]

But, when I created browser instance using the Microsoft Edge WebView2, I see that process as well present. Since, both are chromium based I was thinking same set of processes to be present.

[image]

Any explanation should greatly be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both CefSharp and MS Edge WebView2 are based on Chromium, so both libraries use multi-process architecture.

The `msedgewebview2.exe` process with the `--embedded-browser-view=1` command line parameter you see when running MS Edge WebView2 represents a main Chromium process. It doesn't have `--type=...`.

In CefSharp you don't see the main Chromium process, because CefSharp initializes Chromium inside a .NET application which might have absolutely different name.

So, the behavior you see is expected and there's nothing strange or unusual if you know how it works inside ;)

Comment: The reason why I'm checking was, in WebView2 there is way to handle app failure via the `ProcessFailed` event when `--embedded-browser-view=1` process is killed. We are able to handle app failure when other processes which have `--type` set. Is there a way to handle app failure when the process `--embedded-browser-view=1` is killed? Any modification to the object is resulting in the exception `The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the operation'.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to handle when the main process has been crashed or unexpectedly terminated.